# classList not working in MS-Edge

Tags: javascript, svg, microsoft-edge

I am having an issue where I cannot use javascript's classList on svg elements.

I replicated the issue by this simple piece of code:

**html**

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<circle id="circle" r="40" cx="50" cy="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

**css**

```
.red{
  fill: red;
}
```

**javascript**

```
document.getElementById("circle").classList += "red";
```

JS-fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gqckv029/

I found this ticket on the internet where microsoft states that it has been fixed; https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/1173756/. That doesn't seem to be the case to me.

Adding a class is preferred, but alternatively a workaround to change an elements attribute (like fill in this case) **with javascript** of an svg element would also suffice as answer.

Final note: in the real situation I am trying to trigger a css animation, not a background color.

Comment: classList isn't a string ... you'd need `document.getElementById("circle").classList.add('red');` .... in ALL browsers (not just Edge)

Comment: correction,  what your code is doing does work in other browsers and is equivalent to `document.getElementById("circle").classname += "red";` - but if the element already has `class="blue"` this would result in `class="bluered"` - using .add, would end up with `class="blue red"`

Comment: @Jaromanda X Great! That actually seems to fix the issue. I'll make sure to improve my javascripting by using classList.add() from now on. Drop it in as a formal answer and I ll accept it.

Comment: Try assigning to `className` instead of `classList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements class attribute can be accessed using at least two common methods

```
element.className // a string
```

or

```
element.classList // a "DOMTokenList"
```

In other browsers (other than Edge at least for now), `element.classList += "red"` is effectively the same as `element.className += "red"` Which is fine if the element has no class yet

But, if you have

```
<element class="blue">
```

then both `classList += "red"` and `className += "red"` will result in

```
<element class="bluered">
```

using `classList.add` method is probably what you want

```
<element class="blue">
element.classList.add('red')
<element class="blue red">
```

there's also classList.remove and classList.toggle, which makes working with classes easy